# The space in my hangman unity game reads it as a character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code for generating words for my unity Hangman game.

```
public string GenerateWord()
{
    int index = Random.Range(0, useWords.words.Length);
    string word = useWords.words[index];
    GenerateType(index);
    GenerateDetails(index);
    return word;
}
```

```
#region Generating Words
public void NextWord()
{
    ClearSPlitWord();
    GetWord();
    DisplayNumberofCharacter();
}

void GetWord()
{
    word = WordManager.instance.GenerateWord();
    SplitWord();
}

void DisplayNumberofCharacter()
{
    ClearPrevoisCharacters();
   
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        tempWords.Add(Instantiate(wordDisplayerPrefab, wordDisplayerParent));
    }
}

void ClearPrevoisCharacters()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tempWords.Count; i++)
    {
        Destroy(tempWords[i]);
    }
    correctGuess = 0;
    tempWords.Clear();
}

void ClearSPlitWord()
{
    splitedWord.Clear();
}
#endregion
```

I try fixing in prefab I think I can fix there but I doesn't work I try searching on web and YT but they only use one words, I'm new in C# and Unity so I hope you can help me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to check if the char at the current position is a space.
In the end you probably want to check for other special characters like '-' as well.

This could be done by adding a check into your forloop in DisplayNumberofCharacters()

```
if(word[i] == ' '){
   //we have a space here so do something like inserting a prefab that 
   //shows a space or something
}
```

if you are showing the count of your characters you probably want to subtract space or special characters as well.

I am not really sure what your SplitWord() actually does, if it splits the string and there are still spaces etc left you could [trim your string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0)

Comment: it still doesn't work void DisplayNumberofCharacter()
{
    ClearPrevoisCharacters();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        // Skip creating a prefab for spaces
        if (word[i] == ' ') continue;
        tempWords.Add(Instantiate(wordDisplayerPrefab, wordDisplayerParent));
    }
}  my wordlist is stored on scriptable object btw.

Comment: are you sure the comparison is never true? if so your space probably isn't a space but a differnet [whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode)